# Shadow Dom not showing the child element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, shadow-dom

I have written the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <style> p { color: green; } </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>My Future is so bright</p>
<div id='foo'></div>
<script>
  var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
  foo.shadow = document.createElement('p');
  foo.shadow.textContent = 'I am shadow';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is only showing the output:

```
My Future is so bright  // In green
```

I believe the expected output is:

```
My Future is so bright  // In green
I am shadow
```

My understanding is that `I am shadow` wil not show in `green` because that is part of shadowDOM and not the actual DOM.
Also, Is shadow DOM a concept defined in `JavaScript` or is it defined in `HTML`?

Comment: I am expecting `I am shadow` not to show in `green` because that is part of shadowDOM and not the actual DOM. However, in your output it is showing as green. I have some basic understanding of shadowDOM. Can you provide some explanation on it as well.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `appendChild`:

```
  var shadow = document.createElement('p');
  shadow.innerText = "I'm shadow";
  foo.appendChild(shadow);
```